# Windows CE 6.0 Application Error then Application Freezes but works in Windows CE 5

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, mobile, windows-ce

Hello I have a Windows CE Application that works fine in Windows CE 5.0 on MC3090 devices. However we got new Symbol MCs that run Windows CE 6.0 and the application runs but after an exception in the application and the application closes. I get an "Application Error has occured". If I try to open the application again it freezes the entire device and I have to reboot it.

The vendor Symbol/Motorola is saying it's not an OS issue but rather a software issue. I am using .NET Framework 3.5. We're using SQL Compact Mobile 3.5 to connect to a remote SQL Server.

Is there anyway I can find out what is causing the "Application Error"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was some conflict with .net compact framework. The newer devices had 3.5 preinstalled and the application was running in 2.0. Had to specifically tell the application via app.config to target the 2.0 framework.